# How to check status code in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, uri

I have an ansible task wherein uri shall check the `status_code` and it should succeed for any code other than 400. I include all three codes till now 302, 200 and 503. But I don't want to add all success code but a single failure code 400. How can I do this in uri task?

```yaml
  uri:
    url: "{{ kibana_url }}"
    status_code: [200,503,302]
  register: result
  delay: 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `failed_when`:

```yaml
  uri:
    url: "{{ kibana_url }}"
  register: result
  delay: 10
  failed_when: result.status == 400
```

See the [docs of the uri builtin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) and read about [error handling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html), especially about [defining failure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure) for more information on how this works.